# How to add highlight overlay around the widget upon click?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, ui-design

I'm working on simple design system using Flutter. I want to highlight a widget upon selection (click), as you can see in the below images button get highlighted upon click. It gets handle and border.

Challenging part: I don't want layout getting changed as additional space taken by handle and border upon click. I want widget, handle and border are overlaid, so that it wouldn't shift the position of other neighbouring widgets.

[image: before selection]

And after selection

[image]

Comment: you need to use [Overlay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) for that

Comment: @pskink, how ensure overlay has same dimension of the actual widget?  in my intended system, widget may be subjected change its dimension and postion in its lifecycle.

Comment: you need to get the position and the size of your widget by getting its [RenderObject](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html) (more precisely `RenderBox` class)

Comment: i forgot to add that you can get it by calling `BuildContext.findRenderObject` method

Comment: @pskink, thanks for the reply. Im just wondering what happens when widget size changes, do i have ensure highlight overlay has to be re-rendered?

Comment: yes, you have to rebuild it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a `Stack` with the overlay bleeding out of the `Stack` thanks to a `clipBehavior` of `Clip.none`.

[image]
[image]

### Full code

Just copy paste it in a [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) to see it in action.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const kcPrimary = Color(0xFF001989);
const kcSecondary = Color(0xFF239689);

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const [
              Text('Blablablablabla'),
              Text('Blablablablabla'),
              Text('Blablablablabla'),
              PlayButton(),
              Text('Blablablablabla'),
              Text('Blablablablabla'),
              Text('Blablablablabla'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlayButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlayButton> createState() => _PlayButtonState();
}

class _PlayButtonState extends State<PlayButton> {
  bool clicked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        InkWell(
          onTap: () => setState(() => clicked = !clicked),
          child: _mainButton,
        ),
        if (clicked) ...[
          Positioned.fill(
            child: IgnorePointer(
              child: _overlayBorder,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: -20.0,
            left: 0,
            child: _overlayTitle,
          ),
          Positioned(top: 0, right: 0, child: _corner),
          Positioned(bottom: 0, right: 0, child: _corner),
          Positioned(bottom: 0, left: 0, child: _corner),
          Positioned(top: 0, left: 0, child: _corner),
        ],
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget get _mainButton => Container(
        width: 80.0,
        height: 40.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: kcPrimary,
              width: 3.0,
            ),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
              Text('Play'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget get _overlayBorder => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: kcSecondary,
            width: 3.0,
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget get _corner => Container(width: 10, height: 10, color: kcSecondary);

  Widget get _overlayTitle => Container(
        height: 20.0,
        width: 48.0,
        color: kcSecondary,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: const Text(
          'Button',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the sample code, it helped me a lot. further wanted to know, if i have multiple instance of this button. how to select one at a time. I mean border should disappear when i select the other button.